# Ant-contrib - For loop error

Tags: ant, ant-contrib

I am encountering the following error when I try to use Ant-contrib's FOR loop:

```
Invalid type class org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.script.ScriptDefBase used in For task, it does not have a public iterator method
```

My code is as follows:

```
<taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antcontrib.properties">
      <classpath>
        <pathelement location="WTemplateNewIshopForm/jar/ant-contrib-1.0b2.jar"/>
      </classpath>
    </taskdef>
    <taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antlib.xml">
     <classpath>
        <pathelement location="WTemplateNewIshopForm/jar/ant-contrib-1.0b2.jar"/>
      </classpath>
    </taskdef>

<scriptdef language="javascript" name="upstring">
        <attribute name="string" />
        <attribute name="to" />
        <![CDATA[
            var the_string = attributes.get( "string" );
            project.setProperty(
            attributes.get( "to" ),
            the_string.toUpperCase() );
        ]]>
    </scriptdef>

<property name="mulSvcTypes" value="TEST01;TEST02;TEST03;" />

<for list="${mulSvcTypes}" delimiter=";" param="mulSvcType">
                 <upstring string="${mulSvcType}" to="mulSvcTypeuc" />
                 <sql
                     driver="com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver" url="jdbc:db2://test.test" userid="test" password="test">
                     <classpath>  
                         <pathelement path="WTemplateNewIshopForm/jar/db2jcc.jar:WTemplateNewIshopForm/jar/db2jcc_license_cisuz.jar:WTemplateNewIshopForm/jar/db2jcc_license_cu.jar"/>  
                     </classpath>
                     <![CDATA[
                        INSERT INTO TEST.GRP VALUES ('${mulSvcTypeuc}', '${groupdb}', 'Y');
                     ]]>
                     <![CDATA[
                        INSERT INTO TEST.APRV VALUES ('${mulSvcTypeuc}', '${approver}');
                     ]]>        
                 </sql>
                </for>
```

What does the error mean?
Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `for` task supports iterating over nested elements such as lists, filesets or anything with an `iterator()` method. It also supports iterating over both the `list` attribute AND nested elements, if both are given. The task to actually repeat (i.e. the "body" of the for loop) needs to be inside a `sequential` element.

The error means your first inner task is being treated as something to iterate over instead of the body of the loop like you want. Since it doesn't have an `iterator()` method, it's throwing an error.

To fix this, try surrounding your two inner tasks with a `sequential` task.

See http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/for.html for further information.